# Should I temporarily cover my exposed soffit during a rain storm?

Tags: soffit

We're currently getting our Soffits replaced by a contractor. Unfortunately he has not yet finished the job and they are quite exposed. I'm especially worried about mold growing underneath since I will rain tonight. First, should I be worried and second what can I do to prevent it?

[image: View under soffit]

Comment: Don't worry:  Rain can't fall up, so it should stay dry.  When is the contractor going to finish the soffits?

Comment: Should be tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mold will not be a problem unless the area gets and stays wet.

Of more concern would be birds, bugs and squirrels.  Landscape fabric could be stapled quickly and cheaply, if it will be several days.

Comment: When we took it out too, several foam boards fell out. The contractor said we wouldn't really need them. Is this true? What do they actually do?

Comment: foam boards? probably insulation.  Not much point insulating the soffit area.

Comment: @StevenLu The foam boards are surely insulation. Depending on the type of ventilation and insulation in the attic, you may indeed need/want them replaced.

Comment: I never heard of putting insulation on a soffit.  The whole point is air flow.

Comment: @StevenLu are the foam "boards" that you refer to the same white channel shaped foam pieces visible running between the rafters in your picture? If so, you may wish to replace them--they are to direct the air flow near your roof.

Answer (score 1):

The foam boards, most likely pink in color are called Rafter Vents (owens corning).  They are in integral part of the ventilation system in your attic to keep your house cool/warm in the correct seasons.  Also adds to the longevity of your roofing shingles etc.  They also can help prevent Frost/water ice dams from occurring under the shingles in cold weather.  So when he tells you they're not needed??  you need to think of what else he doesn't know.

The rafter vents slide in between your rolled in or blown in insulation at the base of the roof line leading to the soffit in between each or the roof rafters.  They "push down" the insulation just enough to give you an air space for air flow between the interior of the roof and the soffit. (Make sure he uses vents in your soffit and not just side wall vents).  Air flow is important.

Don White.